# selecting table from other database codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

How can I make this function

```
public function get_all_summary($year_dummy){
    $current_year = $this->session->userdata('curr_year');  
    $new_db = $this->load->database('budget_db', TRUE);

    $q = "select * from budget where sy=$current_year
    AND sy_dummy=$year_dummy";
    $query = $new_db->query($q);
    return $query->result();}
```

to somewhat like this.

```
public function get_all_summary($year_dummy){
    $current_year = $this->session->userdata('curr_year');  
    $new_db = $this->load->database('budget_db', TRUE);

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('budget');
    $this->db->where("sy",$current_year);
    $this->db->where("sy_dummy",$year_dummy);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();}
```

The top function is correct but the bottom function is obviously wrong(I don't know how to select table from other db). I'm also connecting to other database and I'm selecting table from the other database(budget_db).

Hope you understand my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to use `$new_db` which is instance of budget_db.

```
public function get_all_summary($year_dummy){
    $current_year = $this->session->userdata('curr_year');  
    $new_db = $this->load->database('budget_db', TRUE);

    $new_db->select('*');
    $new_db->from('budget');
    $new_db->where("sy",$current_year);
    $new_db->where("sy_dummy",$year_dummy);
    $query = $new_db->get();

    return $query->result();
}
```

Hope this might be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Supposedly, 'budget_db' is the other database you are trying to connect to, make sure it has its own group defined in the database config. Otherwise, you can connect to it using

```
public function get_all_summary($year_dummy){
    $current_year = $this->session->userdata('curr_year');
    $config['hostname'] = "hostname";
    $config['username'] = "db_user";
    $config['password'] = "db_pass";
    $config['database'] = "budget_db";
    $config['dbdriver'] = "mysql";
    $new_db = $this->load->database($config, TRUE);

    $new_db->select('*');
    $new_db->from('budget');
    $new_db->where("sy", $current_year);
    $new_db->where("sy_dummy", $year_dummy);
    $query = $new_db->get();

    return $query->result();
}
```

By adding the parameter TRUE to the load database method, $new_db becomes the database object of budget_db.